# FutureBuilder vs Streambuilder

Tags: database, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, mobile-application

Hello everybody I want to fetch data from cloud firestore, but I am not quite sure which is more efficient to use in flutter. Should I use a streambuilder or a futurebuilder. I have red many posts, but I did not quite understand the differences. Could anybody tell me if I should use a streambuilder or a futurebuilder for getting data from firestore

Comment: Could you describe what you didn't get? as SO already have so many answers for it.

Comment: I did not get which method is efficient for getting data from firestore, as I dont want to make many requests to firestore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `StreamBuilder` and `FutureBuilder` have the same behavior: they listen to changes on their respective object. And trigger a new build when they are notified of a new value.

Eventually, the difference comes in how they listen to the `async calls`.

**FUTUREBUILDER**

It has one and only one response. A very common usage of flutter `Future` is during the `http` calls. What you can do with `Future` is to listen to it's state, that is, when it is done or had an error after the fetching data is done via `Future`

**STREAMBUILDER**

`Stream` on the other hand are `Iterators`, that it can assimilate different values, which will change over time. By using `Stream`, **you will get each new values and also if it has some error or it is done with a success message**

**Representation:**

```
switch (snapshot.connectionState){
   case ConnectionState.none: //do something
   break;
   case ConnectionState.waiting: //do something
   break;
   case ConnectionState.active: //do something
   break;
   case ConnectionState.done: //do somethin
   break;
}
```

The above, will run every time, and updates the value if there is a change in the value coming from async data, even when you are using the app. It doesn't stop. And shows the data which you put inside a particular cases.

**NOW FINAL ANSWER**

If the above still doesn't hit you clearly, than, take a look at the below data:

1. If your use case is to just get the data, and display it, like `Total number of courses from a class from API`. Then you can use `FutureBuilder`.
2. What if, the data updates every second or minute, while you use the app, like `upcoming posts in a blog` or `increase comments on the blog` or `increase in likes on the blog`. It updates asynchronously at certain interval, in that case `StreamBuilder` is the best option.

Bases upon the use case, you decide which one to use. Both of them are good in their own way. Follow the below articles, to get clarity:

- [StreamBuilder class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)
- [FutureBuilder class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)